# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'

Tags: c++, exception, stack-trace

I have this binary thats crashing by throwing an exception of type std:string.

Stack trace from a stripped binary:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'
*** Aborted at 1309483487 (unix time) try "date -d @1309483487" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @       0x3fb0c30155 (unknown)
*** SIGABRT (@0xd54) received by PID 3412 (TID 0x40d03940) from PID 3412; stack trace: ***
    @       0x3fb180de70 (unknown)
    @       0x3fb0c30155 (unknown)
    @       0x3fb0c31bf0 (unknown)
    @     0x2aaaaab80cc4 (unknown)
    @     0x2aaaaab7ee36 (unknown)
    @     0x2aaaaab7ee63 (unknown)
    @     0x2aaaaab7ef4a (unknown)
    @           0x4c2622 XYZ::connect()
    @           0x4c3e0f XYZ::refresh()
    @       0x3fb18062f7 (unknown)
    @       0x3fb0cd1e3d (unknown)
```

Now the thing is, the refresh() function does try to catch std::string. It looks like:-

```
bool XYZ::refresh() {
  try {
    connect();
  } catch (string& s) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any idea why is it not getting caught? Or Am I reading the stack trace wrong?

Comment: I would try to catch a `const string&`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps some or all modules were compiled with `-fno-exceptions`? See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html for details on how that changes exception behavior.

For example, the following short program displays `"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'"` if:

- the module that contains `foo()` was compiled with `-fno-exceptions`, and
- `foo()` calls something that throws an exception of type `std::string` (all other modules were compiled with `-fexceptions`)

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int foo();

  int main()
  {
      try {
          foo();
      }
      catch (string& s) {
          std::cout << "caught it: \"" << s << "\"" << endl;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Note that if I simply recompile `foo.cpp` with -fexceptions (g++'s default) and relink, the program displays:

```
caught it: "the string exception"
```

as expected.

---

Or perhaps some intermediate function had a throw specification that didn't list `std::string`?

For example, this program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Hunc() throw(int); // can only throw int (?)

int main()
{
    try {
        Hunc();
    }
    catch (string& s) {
        std::cout << "caught it: \"" << s << "\"" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


int Hunc() throw(int)
{
    throw string("the string exception");
}
```

Also displays "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'".  Both examples were tested on a Windows box with MinGW 4.5.1.

Comment: Why does the last program shows the instance is of `std::string`? It should be `int` ideally?!

Answer (score 0):

That [should be fine](http://codepad.org/LxEWsyoF).

Perhaps you did not rebuild *all* your source files, or you're running an out-of-date executable.